# R Faster alternative for nested loops

Tags: r, loops, nested, apply

I want to perform a wilcox-Test. I have 2 lists of dataframes. The Datalist contains the number of different observations in a 2 years period. The Varlist contains the Case and Control-Days in different scenarios.

I want to examine now, if there is a difference between the number of each observation and the different scenarios of case and control days. Therefore I use wilcox.test(~).

As output I would like to have a dataframe including the 2 values for Case and Control, the p-Value and of course all list and column-names to match the results correctly.

I have a working solution with an 4 times nested Loop, but its terribly slow (would take 10 days at least). Does anyone know how to solve this with a much faster code?

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 365
df1 = data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), "day"),
                  D1 = sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                  D2 = sample(0:7, n, replace=TRUE),
                  D3 = sample(0:10, n, replace=TRUE),
                  D4 = sample(0:4, n, replace=TRUE),
                  D5 = sample(0:23, n, replace=TRUE))
set.seed(7) 
n <- 365
df2 = data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), "day"),
                 D1 = sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D2 = sample(0:7, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D3 = sample(0:10, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D4 = sample(0:4, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D5 = sample(0:23, n, replace=TRUE))

set.seed(9) 
n <- 365
df3 = data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), "day"),
                 D1 = sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D2 = sample(0:7, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D3 = sample(0:10, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D4 = sample(0:4, n, replace=TRUE),
                 D5 = sample(0:23, n, replace=TRUE))

Datalist = list(df1, df2, df3)

set.seed(2) 
n <- 365
Var1 = data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), "day"),
                 V1 = sample(c("Case", "Control", NA), n, replace=TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(c(NA, "Case", "Control"), n, replace=TRUE),
                 V3 = sample(c("Control", "Case", NA), n, replace=TRUE))

set.seed(6) 
n <- 365
Var2 = data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), "day"),
                  V1 = sample(c("Case", "Control", NA), n, replace=TRUE),
                  V2 = sample(c(NA, "Case", "Control"), n, replace=TRUE),
                  V3 = sample(c("Control", "Case", NA), n, replace=TRUE))

set.seed(23) 
n <- 365
Var3 = data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), "day"),
                  V1 = sample(c("Case", "Control", NA), n, replace=TRUE),
                  V2 = sample(c(NA, "Case", "Control"), n, replace=TRUE),
                  V3 = sample(c("Control", "Case", NA), n, replace=TRUE))

Varlist = list(Var1, Var2, Var3)
```

EDIT: Here is my Code:

```
Results = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 0))
colnames(Results) = c("Code","ICD", "Cond", "Case", "Control", "pValue", "Ver")

for (a in 1:length(Datalist)) {
  print(names(Datalist)[a])
  for (b in 2:length(Datalist[[a]])) {
    for (c in 1:length(Varlist)) {
      for (d in 2:ncol(Varlist[[c]])){ 
        Ill = Datalist[[a]][,b]
        cutpoint = nrow(Datalist[[a]])
        Group = Varlist[[c]][,d]
        Group = Group[1:cutpoint]
        casecontrol = na.omit(data.frame(Ill, Group)) 
        wiltest = wilcox.test(casecontrol$Ill ~ casecontrol$Group)  
        stats = tapply(casecontrol$Ill,casecontrol$Group,mean) 
        
        Code = names(Datalist)[a]
        ICD = colnames(Datalist[[a]])[b]
        Cond = colnames(Varlist[[c]])[d]
        Case = round(stats[1],2)
        Control  = round(stats[2],2)
        pValue  = round(wiltest$p.value, 2)
        Ver  = names(Varlist)[c]
        
        addrow = c(Code, ICD, Case, Control, pValue, Ver)
        
        Results= rbind(Results,addrow)}}}}
```

Comment: What is your working solution, applied to the example that you give? As it is, you are asking us to optimize code without seeing that code or even having a very clear idea of what that code is supposed to do.

Comment: I added it. I dont really want you to optimize my code, since I dont think there is much to do. I guess with apply or something it would be faster? Unfortunately I love to use loops...but with that much data the loop takes a long time.

Comment: Oh and the "cutpoint" doesnt make sense in my example, but the dataframes in the Datalist do not have the same number or rows in my real data.

Comment: You need to remove the rbind statement from inside the loop.  It is best to pre allocate the space and then assign the values.  Perform a web search on "The R Inferno"

Comment: Ok, and that will speed up everything significantly? Could you please give me an example how to calculate the space correctly?

Comment: See https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf Circle 2 -- Growing Objects. Performing the `rbind` in every iteration is very expensive and will be a major bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two errors:

1. `addrow = c(Code, ICD, Case, Control, pValue, Ver)` only has 6 elements but `Results` is created with 7 columns;
2. `addrow = c(Code, ICD, Case, Control, pValue, Ver)` mixes character and numeric data, coercing everything to character.

The code below solves these errors and speeds up execution by a factor of 2. The results are identical, once the errors above are corrected. The main difference is to reserve memory to store the results before the loops and only create the return data.frame at the end.

```
g <- function(Datalist, Varlist) {
  ntotal <- length(Datalist) * (length(Datalist[[1]]) - 1L) * length(Varlist) * (ncol(Varlist[[1]]) - 1L)
  Code <- character(ntotal)
  ICD <- character(ntotal)
  Cond <- character(ntotal)
  Case <- numeric(ntotal)
  Control <- numeric(ntotal)
  pValue <- numeric(ntotal)
  Ver <- character(ntotal)
  i <- 0L
  for (a in 1:length(Datalist)) {
    print(names(Datalist)[a])
    for (b in 2:length(Datalist[[a]])) {
      for (c in 1:length(Varlist)) {
        for (d in 2:ncol(Varlist[[c]])){ 
          Ill = Datalist[[a]][,b]
          cutpoint = nrow(Datalist[[a]])
          Group = Varlist[[c]][,d]
          Group = Group[1:cutpoint]
          casecontrol = na.omit(data.frame(Ill, Group)) 
          wiltest = wilcox.test(Ill ~ Group, data = casecontrol)  
          stats = tapply(casecontrol$Ill,casecontrol$Group,mean) 
         
          i <- i + 1L 
          Code[i] = names(Datalist)[a]
          ICD[i] = colnames(Datalist[[a]])[b]
          Cond[i] = colnames(Varlist[[c]])[d]
          Case[i] = round(stats[1],2)
          Control[i] = round(stats[2],2)
          pValue[i] = round(wiltest$p.value, 2)
          Ver[i] = names(Varlist)[c]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  data.frame(Code, ICD, Cond, Case, Control, pValue, Ver)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this out and report, how much faster it really is on my whole dataset.

Comment: @Essi I rerun my tests and the speed up is by a factor of around 2, not 3 as originally claimed. And why round the numeric results? If you don't there will be a further speed up.

Comment: Ok, but still good. I just don´t get how it works? I have copied everything and g is just a function right? When I enter g(Datalist, Varlist) I get an error: Error in character(ntotal) : invalid 'length' argument

Comment: @Essi The first line of `g` computes the length or number of rows of the result. `ntotal`. If Your true data resembles the posted data then that first line should run, it's the product of the `for` loops sizes, nothing more.

Comment: I found the problem now! Thanks! I tried it just with Varlist$Var1, so I got no value for length(Varlist). It works now and it sees to be a lot faster than my original version. Thank you so much!